# Playing last video in exo recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

I am using exorecylerview and i am using nestedscrollview for loading more data or performing some actions to know recycler view postion. There is a problem it is playing last video of the recycler view. i am using this code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/myscroll">
  <com.androidwave.exoplayer.ui.ExoPlayerRecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/exoPlayerRecyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#dedede"
      android:dividerHeight="8dp"
      />
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when i remove nested scrolling then it play the video that is on focus so how can i resolve this

Answer (score 1):

I know it is quite late, but it may help some other person.

you need to remove NestedScrollView as ExoPlayerRecyclerView is not getting its own scroll, that is why it is not able to detect the position of video.